# How to pull Hard bounce Emails from Data extension to exclude it from sending Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, sql, automationstudio, data-views

This is my Query. But its not working as expected.Count of Hard bounce list retrieved using Query is different from tracking report hard bounce list :

```
select 
  E.[Email]
from 
  Test_DE E
inner join 
  _bounce B 
on 
  B.SubscriberKey = E.[SubscriberKey]
where 
  B.BounceCategory = 'Hard bounce'
```

Comment: "its not working as expected" is not very informative. Can you please explain what you expect from the query? And why it is not working as expected in it's current form?

Comment: Count of Hard bounce list  retrieved using Query is different from tracking report hard bounce list

Comment: Have you validated duplicates? Bounces on jobs outside just the one you sent? I am assuming as you mention tracking report that this is specific to a single send job. This means your count would be off because the _Bounce DV is across any and every bounces this SubscriberKey has ever had. Meaning the counts would not match unless you limit the DV to just that job as well.

Comment: Believe @Gortonington hit the nail on the head. From the limited info, I believe you're requesting the following:                                                                                                      1) Give me all the hard bounces that have ever occurred over X time period (tracking extract)                                                                                                                                  2) Inner join and give me 1 hard bounce where the subscriber is in all subscribers. This is limiting it to 1 hard bounce per sub

Comment: yes @chorlesbarkley7

Comment: In that case I think @Gortonington should move his comment to an answer, as I would expect the count to be off based on the query. One report you're asking for all hard bounces, the other you're not.

Answer (score 1):

Moving from Comment to Answer to make it easier to find solution:

I am assuming as you mention tracking report that this is specific to a single send job. This means your count would be off because the _Bounce DV is across any and every bounces this SubscriberKey has ever had. Meaning the counts would not match unless you limit the DV to just that job as well.

Essentially, the tracking numbers you see in the tracking report are aligned to just that single send job that was executed. This means that it will only show a hard bounce occuring if it happened in that context.

BUT the Bounce Dataview is all bounces across all send jobs for the past 6 months. This means that a subscriber can have multiple hard bounces here due to the different send job contexts and other variables.

So trying to compare the tracking number to the dataview number from your query is similar to trying to find out why in your fridge you only have 1 popsicle, but when you go to the grocery store, you can find dozens of them.

So, to compare apples to apples, you would want to add a condition to your SQL to target just that job (usually JobID) and that should align contexts.

Comment: this means every send, we need to use JobId to retrieve this right?

Comment: To use jobid in query we need to join sent dataview right?

Comment: @SFMC Jobid is a field in _bounce (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_bounce.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you @Gortonington